# how do i remove registration links in joomla 2.5 - login module

Tags: joomla-2.5, module, registration

I would like to remove the links that appears on the top of my website "Sign In / Register" i already disabled the registration under the user manager however the links still appear there and i want to remove them.

I read in a post that this could be part of the original joomla /components/ elements.

my site is qbtrance.com i want to get rid of them, they are on the right top.

i am using joomla 2.5, thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In file `/templates/theme1155/css/template.css` 
on line 299  in selector `#rt-login-button` add attribute `display:none` like this:

`#rt-login-button {
    text-align: right;
    display: none;
}`

UPDATE:
This solution doesn't remove registration links, just hides them from module's html output (doesn't display them), which is is more than enough most of the time. For the real removal of links it is hard to give a solution without full access to admin backend, because they might be generated either from template or from module.

Comment: That worked perfectly!, thank you very much for your help!

Comment: You're welcome.

Comment: Just to mention that this method doesn't remove the links, rather hiding them from displaying (@Israelm)

Comment: @FFrewin True too. I have updated my answer accordingly. Thanx...

Comment: @FFrewin thanks for making the point, but for now hiding the links works perfect for me, but is good to indicate is not a real removal, and i agree with your update Mirko, the real solution might require a change into the template module. Thanks for sharing your knowledge guys.